# Modal opens and closes when I update a variable using useState

Tags: react-native

Whenever my application opens a modal and I try to update a variable using useState the modal opens and closes alone, in my modal there is a Switch that when I change the value it has to change a variable but it happens that this variable I need to change with useState.

My code

```js
    const OverLay = ()=> {

        return(

            <Overlay animated={true}
                     animationType={"fade"}
                     statusBarTranslucent={true}
                     isVisible={over}
                     hardwareAccelerated={true}
                     onBackdropPress={()=>setOver(false)}
                     overlayStyle={{width:"80%",padding:20}}>
                     
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold", alignSelf:"center", fontSize:20, marginBottom:20}}>A impressão digital</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:17}}>A impressão digital permite-te saltar o PIN e desbloquer o App com a tua impressão digital. A impressão digital só funciona caso
                        o teu smartphone suporte ou configuraste.
                    </Text>
                    <Switch
                        trackColor={{ false: "#ddd", true: Cores.primary }}
                        style={{alignSelf:"center", marginTop:10,marginBottom:20}}
                        thumbColor={isEnabled ? Cores.primary : "#ddd"}
                        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                        value={isEnabled}
                    />
                        <Button
                            title="Fechar"
                            onPress={()=>{

                                setOver(false);

                            }}
                            buttonStyle={{borderColor:Cores.primary}}
                            titleStyle={{color:Cores.primary}}
                            type="outline"
                        />
            </Overlay>
        );

    }
```

Comment: Can you share the entire code, so we can see how you used `useState` and the `toggleSwitch`

Comment: let [nome, setNome] = useState('');
    let [puwas, setPuwas] = useState('');
    let [foto, setFoto] = useState('iu');
    let [modalPass, setModalPass] = useState(false);
    let [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
    let [over, setOver] = useState(false);
    let [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
    let pin1, pin2 = "";